# Convert a DataFrame to another with "case class" type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to pass a "DataFrame" to one of a particular type but it throws me this error. I am new to Scala and I am trying to realize that.

```
case class RegionClass(name: String, count: Int)
implicit val encoder: Encoder[RegionClass] = Encoders.product[RegionClass]
df.groupBy("Region")
  .count().as[RegionClass](encoder)
```

error:

```
>  implicit val encoder: Encoder[RegionClass] = Encoders.product[RegionClass]
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is three problems in your code:

**1. No need to specify the encoder**

Scala and Spark are smart enough to automatically create an encoder.

**2. Your class attribute names don't match the dataframe column names**

Ths first column of the dataframe is `Region` while the first attribute of your case class is `name`. You need to rename it in order to be able to cast a row to `RegionClass`.

**3. The schema of your dataframe does not match the schema of your class**

While the type of `count` is `Int` in your class, the `.count()` method of Spark return a `bigint`. You need to cast it to an `Int` in order to be able to case a row to `RegionClass`.

**Solution**

```scala
df.groupBy("Region")
  .count()
  .select(
    'Region as "name",  // rename the "Region" column to match class attribute name
    'count cast "int"  // cast the "count" column to match class attribute type
  )
  .as[RegionClass]
```